# How to multiply a set of columns with another set of columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, combinatorics

Consider the following matrix:

```
set.seed(3)
nn <- 9 # This is always fixed
mm <- 6 # This is always multiple of 3. Other possible values are 9,12,15 etc. 
testMat <- matrix(rbinom(nn*mm,1,.5), nrow = nn, ncol = mm)
```

I am trying to take the product of all the possible combinations of the first 3 columns and the next 3 columns. From the help of solutions found in internet, I can do it in following way:

```
testMat1 <- testMat[,1:3]
testMat2 <- testMat[,4:6]
t(sapply(1:nn, function(i) tcrossprod(testMat1[i, ], testMat2[i, ])))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

However, it requires me to separate the testMat manually. I am trying to automate this process where `mm` is greater than `6`, for example, `9`. Can you suggest an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution to the question I asked. However, I would appreciate it if someone can propose a more elegant solution.

```
test.WinCombo <- matrix(NA, nrow = nn, ncol = 3^(mm/3))
for (i in 1:nrow(testMat)){
  temp.split <- split(testMat[i,],ceiling(seq_along(testMat[i,])/3))
  test.WinCombo[i,] <- apply(expand.grid(temp.split), 1, prod)
}
```